# Uploading image using Google Volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to upload an image using Volley library in android but no data is being send to the server side as the file is created but it does not contain any data.

```
 public class ProfilePicSendReq extends Request<String>
 {
     private MultipartEntityBuilder mBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mImageFile;
    protected Map<String, String> headers;
    Context context;

public ProfilePicSendReq(Context cntxt, String url, Listener<String> listener,  ErrorListener errorListener, File imageFile)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mImageFile = imageFile;
    buildMultipartEntity();
    context = cntxt;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
{
    headers = super.getHeaders();
    if (headers == null
            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap()))
    {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    headers.put("Accept", "text/plain");

    return headers;
}

private void buildMultipartEntity()
{
    mBuilder.addBinaryBody(mImageFile.getName(), mImageFile, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), "profilePic");
    mBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mBuilder.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    String contentTypeHeader = mBuilder.build().getContentType().getValue();
    return contentTypeHeader;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("PicUploadMsg : ", "IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream bos, building the multipart request.");
    }

    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{

    String result =  new String(response.data);
    return Response.success(result, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response)
{
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
}
```

It is the famous sending Mulipart data using volley i have tried several time but no data appears to leave from the client side.